# Clear Google Sheet Cell contents based on another cells value

Tags: google-sheets

I have an issue with my google sheet. I'd like to clear the contents of a cell based on the value of another cell.

For example, I have a drop-down list in cell H3. If the value in cell I3 is 29 or 36 I need the contents of cell H3 to disappear. The ability to use the drop-down menu in H3 should remain for use at a later time.

Currently, I have H3 conditionally formatting to change the font white in H3 when 29 or 36 appear but this is obviously a bit rubbish. I have tried dependent lists using `=INDIRECT` but they don't update immediately or automatically and you soon become trapped. Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create proxy drop-down controlled with **`IF()`**:

```
=IF(OR(I3=29, I3=36), ,{L3:L})
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks, I can see what this is trying to do, but maybe my work is a little different to the example I shared. Here is a link to an example spreadsheet I have setup...

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aady0qCYYiTCHGSH2CgRhQw71rCQ80Mq9NsGOya6szE/edit#gid=260438004)

What we need is when C3 is 29 or 36, B1 clears completely. At the moment using the proxy way, it causes an error, even though it is doing what it should, logically.

Comment: I see your point but this is all you can do (apart of what you already mentioned with font color change) by standard (non-script) means.